# vim 8.0.987 starting every blank file with strange characters

Tags: linux, vim

I have recently installed vim8 from its source code. It is showing the following characters when opening vim with or without file:

```
$q q
```

Does it serve any specific purpose or I have made something unusual mistake while installations.

It is coming even on nerdtree directory structure at top.

Thanks for the helps

Comment: Could it be a side-effect of your vimrc file? Can we see it?

Comment: No vimrc file. Only just installed vim-8.0.987 from source with python and python3.6 and lua support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either a bug in the latest source or an inadvertently exposed terminal incompatibility.

All of the following fixes work for me:

```
set t_SH=
```

or

```
if !empty($TERM_PROGRAM) && $TERM_PROGRAM == 'Apple_Terminal'
 set t_SH=
endif
```

or

```
autocmd VimEnter * redraw!
```

([Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/CAcZNGS2x-8/w3le7odJAAAJ))